# Как настроить автоотключение тачпада при подключении мыши на Linux (Debian.12)

Tags: linux, debian, touch

Всем привет, хочу настроить автоотключени тачпада, когда подсоединяю мышь, но не знаю как это сделать. Раньше была просто проблема с отключением тачпада, а точнее, я не знал как и где его можно мгновенно выключить, но я решил её создав файл `80-synaptics.conf` в директории `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.

Выглядит он примерно таким образом:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "touchpad"
MatchIsTouchpad "on"
Driver "libinput"
Option "Ignore" "false"
EndSection
```

Но теперь думаю, что было бы неплохо, если я бы настроил, что когда мышь не подключена, то тачпад автоматически включался бы, а если была бы подключена, то отключался. Но пока нигде не могу найти годных советов и инструкций как это сделать. Поэтому, кто сталкивался с данной проблемой и сможет подсказать, как её решить, то буду очень благодарен

Comment: [Disable touchpad on mouse detection](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Touchpad_Synaptics#Disable_touchpad_on_mouse_detection)

Comment: почему просто кнопкой на клавиатуре не выключать?